# typescript 'keyof' change the origin property optional?

Tags: typescript, option-type, required, keyof

Define an interface like this

```
interface Props {
  a?: string
  b?: string
  c?: string
  d: string
}
```

When I do something like this, it is ok

```
type Test1 = {
  [P in keyof Props]: Props[P]
}

const a1: Test1 = {
  d: '1'
}
```

but, like this, I got some error message

```
type Keys = keyof Props;

type Test1 = {
  [P in Keys]: Props[P]
}

// error Type '{ d: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Test1': a, b, c(2739)

const a1: Test1 = {
  d: '1'
}
```

Another one

```
type MyOmit<T, K extends keyof any> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }

// Property 'a' is missing in type '{ d: string; }' but required in type 'MyOmit<Props, "b" | "c">'.
const o1: MyOmit<Props, 'b' | 'c'> = {
  d: '1'
}

// Its Ok!
const o2: Omit<Props, 'b' | 'c'> = {
  d: '1'
}
```

Why MyOmit get error?

Answer (score 2):

There is a huge difference between `type Test1 = {  [P in keyof Props]: Props[P] }` and `type Test2 = { [P in Keys]: Props[P] }`.

See first one:
[image]

Each property is optional.

And second one:
[image]

Each property is required but might be `undefined`.

Please see [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) flag.

The reason why TS used this approach is dynamic nature of JS.

Consider this example:

```js
const foo = { name: undefined }
foo.name // undefined
foo.surname // undefined
```

JS returns `undefined` if you are trying to get  property which does not exists.
You can find more explanation in [ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes).

While this flag does not affect the behavior of your example - it gives you nice official explanation of the error you are getting.

If you want to make it work, you just need to make `Test2` partial:

```js
type Test2 = { [P in Keys]?: Props[P] } // <---- added question mark
```

OR:

```js
type Test2 = Partial<{ [P in Keys]: Props[P] }>
```

**Why `keyof Props` is not the same as `Keys`?**

I did not take into account this behavior while answering this question.

Seems to be that in `Test1` - `keyof Props` does not create separate intermediate union type for Props keys and iterates directly through `Props` interface keys taking into account all modificators, whereas during iteration in `Test2`, TS iterates through union of chars: `a | b | c | d` and knows nothing about `Props`.

I have encounter similar behavior when I was working with enums:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    ONE,
    TWO
}

type Enumerate<Enum extends number | string> = keyof {
    [Prop in Enum]: Prop
}

type Result2 = Enumerate<MyEnum>
```

`Enumerate` should return keys of `MyEnum` which is a union of `ONE | TWO` but it returns `MyEnum`

Comment: i know Test1 and Test2 are different, but why? 'in keyof' does anything more?

Comment: @Ben I made an update

Answer (score 0):

[This is the source of `Omit`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1556)

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

So that's what's the difference here–`keyof` grabs all keys and denotes them as non-optional and constructs an object, whereas `Pick` constructs the object from the original, `T` with optional declaration persisted.

Comment: i know Pick is ok. type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: T[P]; } this is source of Pick. i want to know why just 'in keyof ' is ok, but 'in Exclude' not.

Comment: without Pick, can i define my own Omit?